# Clojure: capture runtime value of function arg, to use in REPL

Tags: debugging, clojure, inline, read-eval-print-loop, vscode-calva

### Problem

My web front-end calls back-end queries with complex arguments. During development, to avoid time-consuming manual replication of those arguments, I want to capture their values in Vars, which can be used in REPL.

### Research

This [article](https://blog.michielborkent.nl/2017/05/25/inline-def-debugging/) shows that inline def is a suitable solution, but I couldn't make it work. After a call from the front-end happened, the Var remained unbound.

I launched the backend with REPL through VS Code + Calva, with the following code:

```clj
(defn get-analytics-by-category [params]
  (def params params)
  ...)
```

And here's the evaluation of the Var in the REPL:

```clj
#object[clojure.lang.Var$Unbound 0x1298f89e "Unbound: #'urbest.db.queries/params"]
```

### Question

Why the code above didn't bound value of the argument to the Var? Is there another solution?

Comment: Try adding a `println` with the value of the arg to verify the function is being invoked, and you are getting the expected value from the frontend.

Comment: @AlanThompson, already tried `println`, the function is invoked as expected.

Comment: What about defining a custom Java class with public static field where you can put the value to read it later?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way that I found is to use [scope-capture](https://github.com/vvvvalvalval/scope-capture) library. It captures all the local variables with addition of 1 line in a function, and then with another 1-liner you can define all those variables as global, which allows you to evaluate in REPL any sub-expression in the function using runtime values.

If you ever spent a lot of time reproducing complex runtime values, I strongly recommend watching their [8-min demo](https://vimeo.com/237220354).

---

My issue with inline-def was likely caused by reloading namespace after the Var was bound to a value. After restarting VS Code and carefully doing everything again, the issue went away.

Comment: You may want to have a look at 'defonce', maybe.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to look at the runtime is to use a debugger.

It is more flexible than scope-capture, but requires a bit more work to make variables available outside an execution.

VS Code's Calva extension comes with one, there's also Emacs packages.